# How to optimize the process of multiple process trying to write to the same log file

Tags: php, asynchronous, architecture, scalability

A website using PHP has very huge traffic say like 5000 of request per seconds.Each of these request try to log data but to a single file. Since at any point of time only one of the request can write to the file the other request are queued up which affects the overall response time. The data needs to be logged, that's important. How can I approach to optimize this scenario.

Comment: Can you log into a database instead, then have a function to process the data tables into a log file?

Comment: You could create a temporary text file for each user (or log entry) and merge the files at specific intervals. Or write a file manager/wrapper that creates a file, adds log entry and queue it for master file entry in the background.

Comment: @Cricket writing log to the db for every request won't be a really good idea. Can't talk about the performance as not benchmarked this.

Comment: @Nitin Sounds good to me. Adds a bit of extra work but will work.

Comment: Use `fluentd` and log it there, and after that you can let `fluentd` write it to a file, MySQL, Mongo, wherever. It's a tool developed exactly for such purposes. Leave the queueing and multiplexing to software that's designed for it.

Comment: @N.B. `fluentd` seems good enough. Currently I am pushing my logs manually to elastic search (using UDP for performance) and using kibana.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options.

1. Since your requirement is to write to one large log file and no where else. You can have your PHP scripts to log these entries to the queue first. There are many  message queuing platforms like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ that you can use. Assuming these log entries are not large payloads, Your user requests that results in an entry into log can be directed to insert a message into the queue. You will have another backend process (may be a php script?) that will simply listen to the queue and keep writing to the log file continually. Here is a detail explanation on how how a client would consume the queue message (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html)
2. You can also use something like Apache [Log4php](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/introduction.html) which is a logging framework that uses the file appending mechanism. You will be able to easily push the information important to you by simply calling a method.

   $logger->info("This is the message to be logged.");

They should handle the complexity of multiple request logging on to the same file. You can even have them them break up the the files by day etc.

Hope this helps!